# Versioning C# projects with visual studio

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, versioning

Recently I got assigned to a new project and now have to create a new version of said project.

Unfortunately I don't quite understand how this works in visual studio.

This is the structure in the solution:

[image: All versions inside the solution]

All of these project versions have the very same files inside. If something inside a file is changed, it is being changed for all versions!
This for example is the 2018 version:

[image: V2018 files]

The same files are inside the 2020 version:

[image: V2018 files]

The name space for all projects seems to be the same (because they use the same files):

[image: Namespace]

Also each version seems to have their own .csproj file:

[image: .csproj of each version]

Version specific code is being controlled with preprocessor variables. Each project also has version specific dependencies.

I have no idea how to add a new version to this solution. I thought adding a new project via right clicking the folder Hosts and then clicking on "Add new project" would work but it creates a new project with an entirely new namespace in a different folder.

Does anyone have an idea how this works and how I could do the same for a 2024 version?

Comment: You could try copying one of the existing ones and editing the csproj to align with what you need for the new version.

Comment: Please tell me the project is in a git repo (or at least _any_ version control system).

Comment: ^^ If it is not: Make a copy. NOW. Make another copy and store it somewhere else, maybe some sort of fileserver (of course company-internally).

Comment: And by "make a copy", they mean put it into source control. It costs you nothing.

Comment: This isn't a common (or good) form of versioning. Work on the latest version that isn't correctly guarded by preprocessor conditions could inadvertently affect an older version. Older versions should be locked.  Whoever designed this setup, or in absence of that person, whoever has previously done maintenance on it, should be the one to explain it to you. If neither of those people are at the company anymore, you need to document the heck out of it once you figure it out.

Comment: @madreflection I actually meant both: literally, as an immediate action, make a "carbon copy" just for safety _and_ get it into source / version control _asap_.

Comment: _"you need to document the heck out of it once you figure it out."_ - and then stop doing it that way. Create a _new_ solution under version control and pick into it the latest working version. When you have that complete, go on with one of the version control based approaches out there.

Comment: @Fildor: Fair enough. I just didn't want OP to feel like they could settle on the literal part alone.

Comment: Now that off the table, you probably need to brace for more "peculiarities" to emerge. BTW: Do you have a team or is that a one-man-show?

Comment: Here's an idea: Try to recreate the setup with a small amount of code that does something trivial. Create a new solution and two projects. Remove one project from the solution, move the .csproj file into the other project's folder, and re-add the project. Now they share the same code by inclusion. That's a sandbox, as well as a [mre] for Stack Overflow.

Comment: If you're going to get anywhere on your task(s), you need to understand this, so the time spent is worth it and management needs to accept that the time spent on this is valuable. It's all in service of the ultimate goal of properly versioning the library and getting it into source control .

Comment: ^^ _"that the time spent on this is valuable"_ And cheaper than you rushing something in an environment you only half-heartedly understand and _then_ break something ...

Comment: There might be some edge cases where such a project structure could be useful, say if there are different business rules for each year to follow. But you really need to talk to your colleges to get an understanding about what you are dealing with. If the projects are used for *version control* it is a huge red flag, of the time-to-find-a-new-employer kind.

Comment: @JonasH: True. I've done it myself, although I used links with globbing instead of putting the projects in the same folder. I needed to build the same code with different package references and slight variations based on which package was referenced. This structure made that very easy. But those were "variants", not "versions".

Comment: And probably well-documented? @madreflection :)

Comment: @Fildor: \*sigh\* *Touché*. No, but it was a personal project. I actually just went back to update it with nullable annotations (hadn't touched it in 5 years) and had no problem remembering how it worked. Not a good example to set, I'm afraid, but I wouldn't have been so cavalier in a professional setting.